# Access convert multi-valued field table

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2016

I've taken over a database that has a table with mutli-valued fields e.g

[image: Current multi valued field example]

I'm trying to convert this into a single-valued field table e.g.

[image: Desired single value field table]

The number in both tables is just an `ID` that refers to a person named `Contact_ID`.

I've tried doing this in both Access using Crosstab queries and Excel with Transposing however I can't produce a new table with multiple examples of the same `Contact_ID` in one column and unique keywords in the second.

Appreciate any suggestions on the best way to do this.

Comment: So you want each comma separated entry on its own row with the same Id number as the original row, right?

Comment: Yes precisely. An option I'm looking into involves a new table with a separate FieldName (Field 1, Field 2 etc) for each keyword and then creating a query from that to show all keywords for each ID and copying that into a new table. It's not particularly elegant and I'm still holding out for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in your multivalue field will be coming from a table in your database.

To return the individual items you need to add `.Value` to your query field.

For example,

If `Table1` contains `ID` as an AutoNumber and `MyLookUpItems` as individual items.

```
| MyLookUpID | MyLookUpField |
|------------|---------------|
| 1          | Alcohol       |
| 2          | Smoking       |
| 3          | diet          |
| 4          | Nutrition     |
```

`Table2` contains `MyMultiValueField` showing multiple values.

```
| MyMultiValueField |
|-------------------|
| Smoking, diet     |
| Alcohol, diet     |
```

To return the individual items you'd use:

```
SELECT MyMultiValueField.Value
FROM   Table2
```

This would return:

```
| MyMultiValueField.Value |
|-------------------------|
| diet                    |
| Smoking                 |
| Alcohol                 |
| diet                    |
```

You can then link back to the original ID:

```
SELECT MyLookUpID, MyLookUpField
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.MyMultiValueField.Value = Table1.MyLookUpID
```

which would return:

```
| MyLookUpID | MyLookUpField |
|------------|---------------|
| 1          | Alcohol       |
| 2          | Smoking       |
| 3          | diet          |
```

If you're not sure which is the source for the multivalue fields open the table in design view and look at the `Lookup` tab for the field.
The `Row Source` will look something like:

```
SELECT [Table1].[MyLookUpID], [Table1].[MyLookUpField] FROM Table1 ORDER BY [MyLookUpField];
```

Showing that `Table1` is the source.

*Edit:*
**Now**, having written all that.... just look at the design for the table and the table in the Row Source *is* the single-value field table you were looking for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

With an unknown number of comma-delimited strings, it is likely easiest to iterate over the table using a recordset, use the `Split` function to separate the items, and populate another recordset, e.g.:

```
Function ConvertTable()
    Dim strOldTable As String: strOldTable = "Table1"
    Dim strNewTable As String: strNewTable = strOldTable & "_new"

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngCID As Long
    Dim itm

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    DoCmd.CopyObject , strNewTable, acTablem, strOldTable
    dbs.Execute "delete from [" & strNewTable & "]"

    Set rst1 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strOldTable)
    Set rst2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strNewTable)
    If Not rst1.EOF Then
        rst1.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst1.EOF
            lngCID = rst1!Contact_ID
            For Each itm In Split(rst1!Field1, ",")
                If Trim(itm) <> "*" Then
                    rst2.AddNew
                    rst2!Contact_ID = lngCID
                    rst2!Field1 = Trim(itm)
                    rst2.Update
                End If
            Next itm
            rst1.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rst1.Close
    rst2.Close
    Set rst1 = Nothing
    Set rst2 = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Function
```